# Collect Static Error when trying to deploy Django application to heroku

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, whitenoise

I have put a decent amount of work into my first Django project and I wanted to host it on heroku. I have seen some proposed solutions to this error elsewhere but everything I've tried doesn't seem to fix the error.I've been trying to fix this for 6 hours so I figuered I'd just ask. I'm trying to use whitenoise for the static files. Static files will load fine in my local server, and I can run collect static in my console without any error.

Here is the error

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "/tmp/build_93107b5e_/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
           main()
         File "/tmp/build_93107b5e_/manage.py", line 18, in main
           execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
           utility.execute()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
           self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
           self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
           output = self.handle(*args, **options)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 194, in handle
           collected = self.collect()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 109, in collect
           for path, storage in finder.list(self.ignore_patterns):
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 130, in list
           for path in utils.get_files(storage, ignore_patterns):
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py", line 23, in get_files
           directories, files = storage.listdir(location)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 316, in listdir
           for entry in os.scandir(path):
       FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build_93107b5e_/static'
     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
       See traceback above for details.
       You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
       Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
          $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
     Push failed
```

Here is my settings.py file:

```
from pathlib import Path
import django_heroku 
import os


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['premtable.herokuapp.com','127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'table',
    'django_filters'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'PremTable.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'PremTable.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'premtable',
        'USER': 'xxxxxxxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxxxx',
        'HOST': 'database-1.casge6lscm2l.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}



# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/



STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')


django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Here is my Procfile

```
web: gunicorn PremTable.wsgi --log-file -
```

And here is my requirements

```
asgiref==3.3.1
boto3==1.16.35
botocore==1.19.35
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.1.3
django-filter==2.4.0
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-storages==1.10.1
gunicorn==20.0.4
jmespath==0.10.0
Pillow==8.0.1
psycopg2==2.8.6
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.4
s3transfer==0.3.3
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
unicorn==1.0.2
urllib3==1.26.2
whitenoise==5.2.0
```

Comment: Hi yes I made a small typo there that I fixed thanks for pointing it out, I'm still getting an error however I have updated it above.

Answer (score 1):

First upgrade heroku app by following line
 `heroku stack:set heroku-18 -a <app name>`
Then
`git commit --allow-empty -m "Upgraded heroku-18"`
Then push it
`git push heroku master`
It should work ,if it doesn't then delete `runtime.txt`file and then commit and push on git and then again try to push by
`git push heroku master`
I hope it work for you.

Comment: I have tried your recommendations, and made the typo change suggested above, getting a different error now. I have updated it above in the meantime I will look around and see if I can solve it. Thanks